# Trigger TFS 2010 Team Build on success of another build

Tags: workflow, tfsbuild

Using TFS 2010 Team Build workflow builds, I'm looking for the cleanest way to chain two builds, such that if the first one is successful the second one would be run.

Answer (score 4):

I see two options:

1. Add an activity in the build that starts another build.
   Since the Lab Management Build Process Template contains much of this logic you can re-use these activities.
2. Use the CI trigger on the second build. Put in a dummy folder in the workspace of Build2. Build1 checksin a file in that folder when it is ready. Build2 will automatically be triggered then.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip in point 1. This was a huge help to me today. Thank you again.